# Reactjs : Is it possible to receive AWS SNS on Reactjs web app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to receive realtime communication from my backend, which is rail, and use AWS SNS service to send message to frontent which is react. I can't find a way to subscribe and receive message via http from react.

Is this possible? If it is, how can i implement it? Do I need any extra library to do this?